# Create new HG project from clone of another

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branching-and-merging

I'd like to have a repository that's a framework I use for several projects. I'd like to be able to clone the framework, then make that clone into a brand new project. I'd also like to still be able to push changesets from the framework, though it's not nessecary.

Comment: Would a simple clone not accomplish this? Changes could be pulled over from the framework.

Comment: @Charles I'd like for them to be seperated in some manner. I plan on having several clones of the framework that will become full-fledged projects that have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: Do you plan on/want to send changes to the framework code both ways after cloning or only from the original and out to the new projects?

Comment: @Lasse only one-way, from the old framework to the new projects. this way, if say for example I'm using Wordpress and they update from 3.1 -> 3.2, i can update projects by just doing an hg push

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want changes to the framework-only files to get pushed to the framework repo, but of course you don't want other project-specific changes to get pushed.

If you are able to use the framework code as a separate entity, and just #include it (to use C++ terminology) into your project code, then I would suggest looking into subrepos.

Setting up the framework as a subrepo would mean that your new project would contain the framework as a sub-directory.  If one of your projects updated the framework, you could push just that subrepo, and pull it in other projects, meaning they could all use the latest version, or be locked down to a specific version of the framework.

The [documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) covers how it works, or there are likely some useful hints on setting them up here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repository using the normal `hg clone` operation.

The default path for `hg push` will be the location you cloned from, but you can happily do an `hg push <other_loc>`.

If, as I suspect, you want to make the default path for push and pull something new, you can simply edit the `[paths]` section of `.hg/hgrc`. For example, if you started with this:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@someserver/myrepo
```

You can change it to

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@someotherserver/mynewrepo
source  = ssh://hg@someserver/myrepo
```

This way you can pull from `source` if needed.

You can even configure different default push and pull paths, as documented [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths)